# Why i am getting Post Not Allowed (405)?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am working with AngularJs, Bootstrap in front end and Java- Spring MVC -Spring security-Hibernate in the backend.
1. So i created a user
2. I log in
3. I fill the profil form and when a save, i have a 405 error.

I don't understand why i am getting a 405 error when i make a post request.

This is my request send from a AngularJS service :

```
save : function(user) {
            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/app-web/user/profil/'+user.id+'/create',

                data:user
            })
```

I have `http://localhost:8080/app-web/user/profil/49/create failed with status 405`
Here is my Spring Security config file snippet :

```
<sec:http realm="Protected API" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"  create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="unauthorizedEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <sec:custom-filter ref="authenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/profil/**" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="permitAll" />
    </sec:http>
```

My Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user")
public class UserProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/profil/{userid}/create", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createProfil(@RequestBody User user){
        // my logic
        return "OK";
    }

}
```

Spring log :

```
21:40:40.617 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - Authorization successful
21:40:40.617 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor - RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
21:40:40.617 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /user/profil/49/create reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
21:40:40.617 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] INFO  c.d.j.web.filters.SimpleCORSFilter -  Request ====> 127.0.0.1 ===> java.util.Collections$2@25709a84
21:40:40.623 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'app' processing POST request for [/app-web/user/profil/49/create]
21:40:40.625 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /user/profil/49/create
21:40:40.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/user/profil/49/create]
21:40:40.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for request [/user/profil/49/create] are [/**]
21:40:40.627 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/user/profil/49/create] are {}
21:40:40.628 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/user/profil/49/create] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@663ef60] and 1 interceptor
21:40:40.629 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@663ef60]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
21:40:40.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@663ef60]: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
21:40:40.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] WARN  o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported
21:40:40.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'app': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
21:40:40.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
21:40:40.630 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
21:40:40.631 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Comment: Have you checked out any of the numerous other questions dealing with Spring MVC and the 405 error?

Comment: Yes i checked others post but no one could help me.

Comment: Look at your log, it provides the clue.

Comment: If you how to resolve this error, could you give me some explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a inattention error the class was not set as Controller. So i change the UserProfilController to

```
@Controller
public class UserProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/user/profil/{userid}/create", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String createProfil(@RequestBody User user){
        // my logic
        return "OK";
    }

}
```